# Table Representation in C++

Tags: c++, class

Basically, say, I have the following data:

[image]

*(let me note that the columns change with every piece of data I get, i.e. I need to keep things general and cannot restrict my solution to only Tenor, Date, etc.)*

Now I want to be able to represent and conveniently access this data in an object/class in C++.

I have been playing around with `map` a bit:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class my_table {
private:
    map<string, map<string, string>> c;

public:
    void set(string key1, string key2, string value){ this->c[key1][key2] = value; }

    string get(string key1, string key2){
        map<string, map<string, string>>::iterator it = this->c.find(key1);
        if (it != this->c.end()){
            map<string, string>::iterator it2 = this->c[key1].find(key2);
            if (it2 != this->c[key1].end()){
                return c[key1][key2];
            }
            return "n/a";
        }
        return "n/a";
    }
};

void main() {
    my_table a;
    a.set("1", "Tenor", "1D");
    cout << a.get("1", "Tenor") << endl; // returns '1D'
    cout << a.get("2", "Tenor") << endl; // returns 'n/a'
    cout << a.get("1", "Rate") << endl;  // returns 'n/a'
}
```

But I am not overly satisfied with this implemenation. In particular, I would want to be able to do things like:

```
a.get("Tenor","3M", "Rate")                   // should return '1.6%'
a.get("Date","01-Jan-2016", "Responsibility") // should return 'MG'
a.get_all("Type","Forward", "Rate")           // should return an array {1.3%,2.4%}
a.get_row(4)                                  // should return an array {4M,...,2.0%,MG}
```

And:

- I am wondering whether there are there any standard packages that could help me simplify this implementation overall?
- In particular, my `get` function seems unnecessarily cumbersome.
- And generally, is `map` is even the right way to go in terms of storing data like this?
- And what if I wanted to generalise this implemenation to more than just 2 keys? Maybe 3 keys. My solution is quite rigid

Comment: Where is your class definition for each "contract"? Seems it would have data members for #, Tenor, Date, Convention, Type, Rate, Responsibility.Then simply create and store them in a vector or map

Comment: Read up on relational database theory, especially *normal forms* and index tables.

Comment: @ Phil-ZXX,  Basically C++ API's for RDBMS-es is one very mature subject. With perhpas several sucesfull implementations.  I might suggest  you start from here. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-cpp/8.0/devapi_ref.html

Answer (score 3):

```
enum struct Type {
  Spot
  Forward
}


struct Row {
  string tenor;
  Date date;
  int convention;
  Type type;
  double rate;
  ResposibilityType responsibility;
};

std::vector<Row> table = {
  [...]
}
```

access you do with `std::find_if`. Tables in databases might be stored like this internally. If you want multiple primary keys you can create for each key a map that maps from the primary key to an element in `table`. If you want a combined key, you need tuple like this `std::map<std::pair<Key1,Key2>, Row*>`

Comment: Let me mention that every piece of data I have has a different set of columns.

Comment: You will need multiple tables if the set of columns changes.  Also figure out some kind of *foreign key* than can be used to *relate* one table record to another.

Comment: You say that "every piece of data I have has a different set of columns."  Okay, but presumably the pieces of data that all go into the same table, with the same header row in the table, have the same set of fields, right?  If not, then you just want a basic two-dimensional array of, say, strings, such as std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>.

Comment: @DanKorn Does std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> bear specific advantages over map<string, map<string, string>> ?

Comment: It works differently.  Whether one is advantageous over the other depends on what you're doing, i.e. what data you're modeling.  If you're looking up values by the key/field/header name, then you want to use a map.  If you're just accessing them positionally, i.e. by row and column number like in Excel, then you probably want a vector.

Comment: Keep in mind that the table you're looking at really is nothing more than a visual representation of a two-dimensional array.  The "special" meaning of the first row as a header with keys (field names) is a special case, which implies a database-type ordering of the data, into records (rows) and fields (columns).  If you want to access the fields/columns by name, then you can represent that data with a map (or possibly a multimap where each key can map to multiple records/rows).  But if you want purely positional access, such as "column 7 in row 3", or "G3" in Excel, that's a 2D array.

Comment: @Tom you have to create a struct for each type of table you want to support. That could be that you have to creat a lot of struct. If you want some dynamic form of table that can change the amount of column at runtime, or where the columns are defined earliest at runtime, you might change your question. At the moment I can only assume you know the columns.

Answer (score 1):

How about the [matrix type](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1%5F38%5F0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/types_overview.htm#matrices) from boost.ublas? You can create a simple enum type to easily reference columns.

For querying you can probably build something quick via the [filter_iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/iterator/doc/filter_iterator.html).

Hope this helps!

Edit: Sorry didn't notice your comment. A quick hack I can think of to support dynamic column size is using a hash map for storing column name to column index mapping in a separate hash map. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Limiting yourself to maps could overcomplicate this somewhat.  If I understand this correctly, the data structure is completely undefined at compile time.  In that case perhaps a simpler way to implement it is as a vector of hash-key-value triples, like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class HashKeyValue
{
private:
    string hash;
    string key;
    string value;

public:
    HashKeyValue() {}
    HashKeyValue(string h, string k, string v)
    {
        hash = h;
        key = k;
        value = v;
    }
    string getHash()  { return hash;  }
    string getKey()   { return key;   }
    string getValue() { return value; }
};

class my_table
{
private:
    vector<HashKeyValue> hkv;

public:
    my_table() {}
    void set(string h, string k, string v)
    {
        hkv.push_back(HashKeyValue(h, k, v));
    }
    string getV(string h, string k)
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < hkv.size(); i++)
        {
            if (hkv[i].getHash() == h && hkv[i].getKey() == k)
                return hkv[i].getValue();
        }
        return "n/a";
    }
    string getByColValue(string col1, string val, string col2)
    {
        string hash;
        int got = 0;
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < hkv.size() && !got; i++)
        {
            if (hkv[i].getKey() == col1 && hkv[i].getValue() == val)
            {
                hash = hkv[i].getHash();
                got = 1;
            }
        }
        if (got)
        {
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < hkv.size(); i++)
            {
                if (hkv[i].getHash() == hash && hkv[i].getKey() == col2)
                    return hkv[i].getValue();
            }
            return "n/a";
        }
        else return "n/a";
    }
};


int main()
{
    my_table m;
    m.set("1", "Tenor", "1D");
    m.set("3", "Tenor", "3M");
    m.set("3", "Rate", "1.6%");
    cout << "get-1-Tenor(1D): " << m.getV("1", "Tenor") << endl;
    cout << "get-1-Alto(n/a): " << m.getV("1", "Alto") << endl;
    cout << "get-3-Rate(1.6%): " << m.getV("3", "Rate") << endl;
    cout << "getBCV-Tenor-3M-Rate(1.6%): " << m.getByColValue("Tenor", "3M", "Rate") << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Hopefully `getByColValue()` makes sense; it first looks up the hash, then looks up the Rate for that hash.  The hash is what relates each key-value pair to others on the same row.  It shouldn't be too tricky to change `getByColValue()` to return a `vector<string>` instead, for the `getByColValue("Type","Forward","Rate")` case: just make hash a `vector<string>` instead, define the return type as another `vector<string>`, and a few other tweaks.

This also makes the implementation of `getRow()` fairly trivial; just loop over hkv where hash==rowid and bung the key/value pairs (or just the values) into a vector.